# Is there a way to access an attribute outside a class?

Tags: python

I want to access an attribute outside a class, but even after googling I don't see any similar solution for this particular problem.

```
class test():
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        pass
    def testpy(self):
        self.x = 'Hello world'

value = test().testpy.x
print(value)

>> AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'x'
```

Comment: Please put code as text in your question. In your code `x` is a local variable, not an "attribute".

Comment: No it is impossible. `testpy()` doesn't return anything so you can't access it's attributes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're confusing local scope, with class attributes, and global scope.

You can achieve your result in one of three ways:

- Creating a class attribute to access
- Using the `return` keyword to return local values
- Using the `global` keyworld to create a globally scoped variable. *Highly* not recommended

```
class test:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.x = "Hello world"
        pass

    def testpy(self):
        self.x = "Hello world"
        x = "Hello world"
        global Y
        Y = "Hello world - global"
        return x

object = test()
value_via_objects_attribute = object.x
value_via_objects_method = object.testpy()
value_via_global = Y

print(value_via_objects_attribute)
print(value_via_objects_method)
print(value_via_global)
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you are confused with what an attribute is.

In your code `X` is a local variable in the member function `testpy`. `X` exists only in that function, and is deleted upon function exit.

If you want a member, write `self.x = 'Hello world'`. This will create and store a data member called x. Additionally, when you write `test().testpy().x` you are calling the member function `testpy()` and are then attempting to call `.x` on the return result, which will obviously break.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `x` is a local variable inside a function, not a class attribute. You can return that variable:

```py
class test():
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        pass
    def testpy(self):
        x = 'Hello world'
        return x

value = test().testpy()
print(value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please go through python class tutorial once more.
`testpy` is a function of class `Test`, it returns None in the above code. `x` is an attibute of class `Test` not function 'testpy'

```
class Test():
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def testpy(self):
        self.x = 'Hello world'

t = Test()
t.testpy()
value = t.x
print(value)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing your testpy() function with your constructor - the **init** method.  In python, you can initialize a new object by calling the class as if it were a function - ex, "value = test()".  When you call this function, the **init** method gets called, and returns a new object (self).  So to declare an attribute on self, in the **init** function (your constructor), you simply write "self.x = "Hello World".

The full solution to your problem is below.

```
class test():

  def __init__(self):
     self.x = 'Hello World'
        
value = test()
print(value.x)
```